# How to print the names of all excel files from a folder to a csv in R?

Tags: r

Request you to please help me with code/script in R which prints all the names of excel file present in a folder .

the name of one of the excel file in a folder is 
chaudhryaman_595_6140_a765tgha01tj9_C_51_M.xlsx

there are 145  similar files and need to print the names of files with R

Comment: See `help("list.files")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
write.csv(list.files("path", pattern="*.xlsx"), file="excel_files.csv")
```

You can change the pattern as per your needs.